# Visual Studio post build command running before SharePoint package is created

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint

I'm updating some VS SharePoint projects so when they are built, both dll's and wsp's (packages) are created.

I found [this](http://www.sharemuch.com/2010/03/23/how-to-package-on-build-in-your-visual-studio-sharepoint-2010-solution/) page describing the process, but issue is that, while my project file looks like this:

```
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\SharePointTools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.targets" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <BuildDependsOn>$(BuildDependsOn);CreatePackage</BuildDependsOn>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PostBuildEvent>"$(SolutionDir)PostBuild.cmd" "$(SolutionDir)" "$(TargetDir)"</PostBuildEvent>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

PostBuild.cmd is run BEFORE packaging happens, so when starting clean, this is the output:

```
------ Rebuild All started: Project: Sample, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
  SampleProject -> C:\Inter\bin\Debug\Sample.dll
  C:\Inter\bin\Debug\Sample.dll
  1 File(s) copied
  File not found - *.wsp
  0 File(s) copied
  Successfully created package at: C:\Inter\Sample\bin\Debug\Sample.wsp
========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Any ideas? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution can be found [here](http://softwarerecipes.blogspot.com/2011/04/visual-studio-sharepoint-how-to-create.html).

> Visual Studio & SharePoint: how to create package as part of the build
>   process In order to build a project and have the package created, this
>   can be added to the project file (csproj, vbproj):

```
<PostBuildEventDependsOn>
  $(PostBuildEventDependsOn);
  CreatePackage;
</PostBuildEventDependsOn>
```

Answer (score -3):

That's right. PostBuild event occurs after buiding assembly.

Comment: Sure... what I'm posting here is that PostBuild is occurring BEFORE package creation...

Comment: @Ariel:I wanted to tell you that this is the correct behavior. If you want to do anything before packaging, use PreDeploymentCommand

Comment: But I don't want to do deployment, only packaging AFTER build and BEFORE PostBuild event, makes sense? I want to click "rebuild" and have the project built, packaged then postbuild command run...